# How can I fix a (possibly) incomplete edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087981/seaborn-how-do-interpret-the-values-of-the-x-axis-in-a-distplot) question and realized that a few things need to be edited in the title and the text. For example, instead of `to`, the title uses `do`. But then I saw that somebody has already edited it and didn't notice these things. Moreover, I don't seem to be able to edit this question now because of that (the link to `edit` is disabled). Why is this so and how can I fix these things?

Comment: Is that still the case now?

Comment: @RobertLongson: I could edit now.

Comment: @Gimby: I think that was the main issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your reputation level you are only allowed to suggest edits. If someone else already suggested an edit, the system doesn't allow you to make further suggestions until that suggested edit has been reviewed. That makes sense as the reviewers might make additional changes and the system would need to make decisions on whether a second (or third) suggested edit in the queue would still be valid.

Just wait until the previous suggested edit has been reviewed that often doesn't take more than an hour. Keep a tab open with that question in your browser, or bookmark the question and come back to it to see if the changes you wanted to make are still necessary.

In the mean time work on answering questions, so you'll get immediate edit priviliges ( at [2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) )